# Android canvas drawColor, I cant seem to use a color defined in xml

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm trying to draw the background of a custom view in the OnDraw method, with a call like this:

```
canvas.drawColor(R.color.red_player_light);
```

Corresponding to an xml file like this called "colors.xml", (I've tried "color.xml" also).
However the result is a black background.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>

         <item name="red_player_light" type="color">#FFF45564</item>

    </resources>
```

If I did canvas.drawColor(Color.Red), i can get a red background, so the ondraw method seems to be working.
Or , using something in the style of

```
canvas.drawColor(Color.parseColor("#F45564"));
```

works, however that is not easily modifiable across different points in the code.

Can anyone spot what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `canvas.drawColor(res.getColor(R.color.red_player_light))`, where `res` is a `Resources` object (e.g., from `getResources()` on `Activity`).

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion, I can get it to work with canvas.drawColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red_player_light)); However, I do not know how to create a resources object as you exactly wrote it. could you be more specific sorry?

Comment: Ok I have that step worked out now. I can just create an int from the color resources and use that

Answer (score 1):

Try defining your resource as a color like this:

```
<color name="red_player_light">#F45564</color>
```

I generally make a separate `colors.xml` file in my res/values folder to hold these values like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
    <color name="aqua">#00FFFF</color>
    <color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>

</resources>
```

Then when you need to access these values in your code you can just call `R.color.red_player_light`

Comment: i changed my colors.xml file to be in your format, however I am still getting a black background with the code: canvas.drawColor(R.color.red_player_light);

Comment: Try doing `getResources().getColor(R.color.red_player_light);`